# How to detect the character before a number in RegEx

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a string `test_demo_0.1.1`.

I want in PowerShell script to add before the `0.1.1` some text, for example: `test_demo_shay_0.1.1`.

I succeeded to detect the first number with RegEx and add the text:

```
$str = "test_demo_0.1.1"
if ($str - match "(?<number>\d)")
{
    $newStr = $str.Insert($str.IndexOf($Matches.number) - 1, "_shay")-
}
# $newStr = test_demo_shay_0.1.1
```

The problem is, sometimes my string includes a number in another location, for example: `test_demo2_0.1.1` (and then the insert is not good).

So I want to detect the first number which the character before is `_`, how can I do it?

I tried `"(_<number>\d)"` and `"([_]<number>\d)"` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Use `"(?<=_)(?<number>\d)"`

Comment: Or,  I guess you just may use `$str -replace '_(\d.*)', '_shay_$1'`

Comment: All above is posted below, please consider accepting.

Comment: Sure. fast and great answer! thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you ask for is called a positive [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (a construct that checks for the presence of some pattern immediately to the left of thew current location):

```
"(?<=_)(?<number>\d)"
 ^^^^^^
```

However, it seems all you want is to insert `_shay` before the first digit preceded with `_`. A `replace` operation will suit here best:

```
$str -replace '_(\d.*)', '_shay_$1'
```

Result: `test_demo_shay_0.1.1`.

**Details**

- `_` - an underscore
- `(\d.*)` - Capturing group #1: a digit and then any 0+ chars to the end of the line.

The `$1` in the replacement pattern is the contents matched by the capturing group #1.